# How to compile c99-to-c89 convertor with clang?

Tags: makefile, ffmpeg, clang, llvm-clang

I'm trying to compile ffmpeg in windows for VisualStudio and one of the step is to compile [c99-to-c89](https://github.com/rbultje/c99-to-c89) code with clang according to [this](http://blogs.gnome.org/rbultje/2012/09/27/microsoft-visual-studio-support-in-ffmpeg-and-libav/) post. I managed to create clang.exe but how I compile c99-to-c89 code with it?

I changed a little bit the makefile in c99-to-c89 so `CC` variable points now to clang.exe compiler and not cl.exe

```
EXT=.exe

all: c99conv$(EXT) c99wrap$(EXT)

CLANGDIR=C:/build
CC=C:/build/bin/Release/clang.exe
CFLAGS=-nologo -Z7 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS=1 -Dpopen=_popen -Dunlink=_unlink -Dstrdup=_strdup -Dsnprintf=_snprintf -I. -I$(CLANGDIR)/tools/clang/include
LDFLAGS=-nologo -Z7 $(CLANGDIR)/lib/Release/libclang.lib

clean:
    rm -f c99conv$(EXT) c99wrap$(EXT) convert.o compilewrap.o
    rm -f unit.c.c unit2.c.c

test1: c99conv$(EXT)
    $(CC) -P unit.c -Fiunit.prev.c
    ./c99conv unit.prev.c unit.post.c
    diff -u unit.{prev,post}.c

test2: c99conv$(EXT)
    $(CC) -P unit2.c -Fiunit2.prev.c
    ./c99conv unit2.prev.c unit2.post.c
    diff -u unit2.{prev,post}.c

test3: c99conv$(EXT)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -P -Ficonvert.prev.c convert.c
    ./c99conv convert.prev.c convert.post.c
    diff -u convert.{prev,post}.c

c99conv$(EXT): convert.o
    $(CC) -Fe$@ $< $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)

c99wrap$(EXT): compilewrap.o
    $(CC) -Fe$@ $< $(LDFLAGS)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -Fo$@ -c $<
```

but when I run `make` command I get `clang: error: unsupported use of internal gcc -Z option '-Z7'`. I guess the problem in `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` but I don't know how to fix it because the lack of knowledge in makefile and clang.

Comment: You can find a pre-compiled binary [here](http://git.chromium.org/gitweb/?p=chromium/third_party/ffmpeg.git;a=tree;f=chromium/binaries).

Comment: @lorcap, did u succeeded to compile and debug ffmpeg with VisualStudio?

Comment: No, I haven't even tried.  The binary I found suits my needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If someone still needs, the guys from libav provided me with [this](https://github.com/libav/c99-to-c89/downloads) link to download the binaries `c99conv.exe`, `c99wrap.exe`, `makedef`

Answer (score 1):

c99conv wust be compilled with msvc compiller, but it uses libraries from LLVM. Actualy, converter uses clang as a parser C99 sources.

Therefore clang needs to be compilled with MSVC (because MSVC will link libclang with c99conv).

So, just lead the build instructions from article you link.

- Run visual studio command promt.
- Run msys shell from mingw.
- Tune Makefile.w32 for your environment
- Compile c99conv with Makefile.w32

```
make -f Makefile.w32
```